# Set iDoc = IE.Document gives run-time error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, ie-automation

I am having strange issue. I am using 32 bit version IE 10. End user is using 64 bit version IE10

For me `set iDoc = IE.Document` works fine in below code snippet. But for end user I get "Type mismatch error".

Below is my code:

```
Function Run() As Integer
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim dataCount%

    Set IE = GetIE

    Navigate IE, "http://www.my-url-here.com/index.php"
    Call Login(IE)
    IE.Quit
End Function

Private Sub Login(IE As InternetExplorer)
    Dim iDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim uName$, pwd$
    Set iDoc = IE.Document   ' here is where it gives type mismatch error

    Call GetLoginDetails(jobBoard, uName, pwd)

    iDoc.getElementById("login").Value = uName
    iDoc.getElementById("pw").Value = pwd
    iDoc.getElementsByClassName("sub_btn")(0).Click

    Sync IE
End Sub

    Sub Sync(IE As InternetExplorer)
        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        Loop

        Do While IE.Document.ReadyState <> "complete"
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        Loop

        'Debug.Print "Out: " & IE.Document.ReadyState
    End Sub

    Sub Navigate(IE As InternetExplorer, address$)
        IE.Navigate address
        Sync IE
    End Sub

    Function GetIE() As InternetExplorer
        Set GetIE = New InternetExplorer

        With GetIE
            .Visible = True

            .Height = 550
            .Width = 800

            .Left = Application.Width - .Width
        End With
    End Function
```

Please note: `IE.Document.getElementById("login").Value = uName` works fine for both of us.

Comment: Have you try with late biding `Dim iDoc As Object`?

Comment: Do `TypeName(IE.Document)` and see if it's actually returning an `HTMLDocument` for the end user? Or, use late-binding per @R3uK suggestion and `Dim iDoc as Object`.

Comment: @R3uK Not yet. Will that help? Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes I did that in immediate window and it actually gives `HTMLDocument`

Comment: @DavidZemens : Thx for the explanation, I didn't know that `Navigate` referenced `ReadyState` (I usually use it afterwards to wait for the page to load fully)!

Comment: Is the end-user using 32-bit or 64-bit excel?

Comment: Did you do that in immediate window on the *user* machine?

Comment: Try `As Object` then, curious to see what happens.  Using the generic `Object` should avoid the mismatch, I would think.

Comment: @TimWilliams: I am using 32 bit Windows-8 and IE. End user is having 64 bit Windows-7 and IE

Comment: But what version of Office?  I'm not sure it's possible to automate 64-bit IE from 32-bit Excel.

Comment: @TimWilliams: we both are having 32 bit version of Excel. I think it is possible.

Comment: @All Please check new note I added at end in question.

Comment: see this article on [Late vs Early Binding](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/InterDev/EarlyvsLateBinding.htm) to help you understand the most likely reason your code is not working on the end-user machine (as well as to thoroughly understand when, why and how to use both)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: Great article. Thanks. I will try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not specific to IE, [this MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/983246) implies that there are known issues with underlying API calls in VBA and x64 systems.

With external/custom API calls, we can accomodate for this using `PtrSafe` and `LongPtr` declarations.

Use late-binding, which I've found worked for me in the past:

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

The downside is that you will lose the [intellisense](/questions/tagged/intellisense) feature - but IntelliSense isn't really that useful if the code doesn't run I guess...

Comment: You can always early-bind to write the code (and thus get intillense) and then modify all the declarations to late-binding before releasing :)

Comment: Thanks. That solved my issue! But I saw another issue in 64 bit operation system. GetElementsByClassName method doesn't work on iDoc (which I declared as Object now) Is this also a known issue? I am not able to install hotfix given by microsoft as I don't have admin rights on that PC but should be able to do tomorrow.

Comment: Not come across it personally - only thing I can think of is make sure the doc is 100% loaded before trying to access elements. Don't forget to mark as answer if it helped! (Green tick on left)

Comment: Document is 100% loaded that I am sure as I am getting this error in break mode as well. Sure, will let you guys know. Thanks for help so far!